# How to call my OOP based classes and methods in PHP when buttons clicked or page loads in purely OOP style

Tags: php, html, oop

**Point 1:**

So I'm a beginner in PHP OOP and have been asked to complete a project for hiring at a company. They have asked in the guidelines to code in PHP OOP only, and have recently returned my project with one of the following point:
**"Procedural PHP code is allowed exclusively to initialize your PHP classes. Rest logic should be placed within class methods."**
Now, I am stuck since I have no clue how to call my php code without instantiating my classes in scenarios like such:

- Perform a save/delete function when a button is clicked
- Show all products from my phpMyadmin database on the homepage automatically
  when the page loads

My frontend is made using basic HTML+ JQuery and I'm required to use php oop for all logical handling.

This is a snippet of my code where when a button is clicked I have used isset to call a function or instantiate a class and added calls to functions in the constructor, I dont know how else to call my functions, like I have to instantiate the objects somewhere and call function on the basis of some check when specific event happens.

```
//placed these checks in a procuctinfo.php class which is called when button save/delete(with action="productinfo.php" method = "post") is clicked 

if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $product = new $_POST['productType'](); //goes to constructor of specific product where method is called to save data
}

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    Product::delete(); // static method called since delete is not object specific
}


//here is my constructor of one of the product classes 
    public function __construct(){ //contructor for one of the products
            parent::__construct();
            if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
                $this->weight =$_POST['weight'];
                **$this->setData()**; //method called within constructor which saves data in my db
            }
        }
```

Similarly for rendering all products on homepage I have embedded php code within my html in the following way,

```
<div class="text-center py-2 px-5 justify-content-center d-flex flex-wrap gap-4">
                    <?php

                    $DVDs = new DVD([]);
                    $result = $DVDs->getAllData();
                    if($result){
                        foreach($result as $product){
                            $productObj = new $product['productType']([]);
                            $productResult = $productObj->getDataProductWise($product);
                            ?>

                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 ">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="bg-image hover-zoom ripple ripple-surface ripple-surface-light"
                                    data-mdb-ripple-color="light">                      
                                    <div class="form-check delete-checkbox">
                                        <input class="form-check-input m-3 border border-dark rounded-0" type="checkbox" name = "deleteChecked[]" value="<?= $productResult['sku'] ?>" id="flexCheckDefault">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title mb-3"><?= $productResult['sku'] ?></h5>
                                    <h6><?= $productResult['name'] ?></h6>
                                    <h6 class="mb-3"><?= $productResult['price'] ?> $</h6>
                                    <h6 class="mb-3"><?= $productResult['attribute']?></h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }

                ?>

            </div>
```

Please guide me if there is some purely OOP based way/approach to do this.

**Point 2:**

I provided them a website link which I created using https://www.000webhost.com/ website but they have asked me to :
**"Please provide FE link."**

What is this and how can I create it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not like to see `$_POST[]` inside a constructor. That's purely my opinion, but I can give some reasons: It's raw user input, think about security, and classes should be created to be flexible, not rigid in that the input **has** to come from the user.

Your code snippets are very short. I cannot do much with those. Only the output code is long enough.

In it I see that you don't actually use objects, you convert them to arrays. Why? `getAllData()` and `getDataProductWise()` should not be used in this code. It should simply be `getProducts()` which should return an array with zero or more product objects.

This means that when you need to display something from an object you do:

```
echo '<h6 class="mb-3">' . $product->getPrice() . '</h6>';
```

You can create a method in the `DVD` class called `outputProductHtml($product)` to output a product and then you can also do:

```
public function outputProductsHtml()
{
    foreach ($this->getProducts() as $product) {
        outputProductHtml($product);
    }
}
```

Keep methods short and simple like this. Now your `DVD` class can generate HTML for a single product or for all products it contains.